# Reading pdf with Apache PDF Box

Tags: java, swing, pdf, pdfbox

I have these lines of codes that I have being trying to use to read pdf file with Apache pdfBox.

```
    private void readPdf(){
    try {
        File PDF_Path = new File("/home/olyjosh/Downloads/my project.pdf");
        PDDocument inputPDF = PDDocument.load(PDF_Path);
        List<PDPage> allPages = inputPDF.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDPage testPage = (PDPage) allPages.get(5);
        System.out.println("Number of pages "+allPages.size());

        PDFPagePanel pdfPanel = new PDFPagePanel();
        jPanel1.add(pdfPanel);
        pdfPanel.setPage(testPage);

//            this.revalidate();
        inputPDF.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I want this pdf to be displayed on swing component like jPanel but this will only display the panel with the expected content of the pdf file. However,  I was able to display the pdf as image using

```
convertToImage = testPage.convertToImage();
```

Please, how do I work around this or what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache PDF-Box has a [mailing list](http://mailto://users@pdfbox.apache.org) where I was able to ask the same question and this was the response I got

> This was removed in 2.0 because it made trouble. Obviously, it doesn't work for 1.8 either, at least for you, so why bother?
>
> There are two ways to display, either get a BufferedImage (renderImage / renderImageWithDPI) and display that somehow (see in PDFDebugger how to do it), or renderPageToGraphics which renders to a graphics device object.
>
> If you really want to get the source code of the deleted PDFReader application (which includes PDFPagePanel), use svn to get revision 1702125 or earlier, that should have it. But if it didn't work for you in 1.8, it won't work for you now.
>
> The point is that swing display of PDF pages isn't part of the API, it's part of some tool (now: in PDFDebugger, previously: in PDFReader)
>
> You need to have some understanding of awt / swing. If you don't, learn it, or hire somebody. (That's what we did, and the best is: google paid it, as part of the google summer of code)
>
> Tilman

Comment: Don't know if you saw it, but I did post some code to the mailing list related to another similar question, maybe this helps: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/201512.mbox/%3C567F0B43.7040301%40t-online.de%3E